# Validate JSON array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oracle-apex

I am trying to write an `if` statement that determines whether the `getDept` JSON array contains more than one value. If it does, then redirect to a different page. Through my research, it seems like it is as simple as `getDept.length > 1`, I have not been able to make this work though.

My Javascript code is as follows:

```
$.getJSON("https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/mfajertest1/department/"+$x('P2_DEPT_NO').value, function(getDept) 
{
    console.log(getDept);
    if(getDept.length == 0)
        {
                window.alert("No Department with that ID");
        }
    else if(getDept.length > 1)
        {   
                apex.navigation.redirect('f?p=71293:11');
        }
    else
        {
    $x('P2_DEPT_NAME').readOnly = false;
    $x('P2_DEPT_NAME').value=getDept.items[0].dname;
    $x('P2_DEPT_NAME').readOnly = true;
    $x('P2_DEPT_LOC').readOnly = false;
    $x('P2_DEPT_LOC').value=getDept.items[0].loc;
    $x('P2_DEPT_LOC').readOnly = true;
    $x('P2_DEPT_NO').readOnly = true;
  }
});
```

**The getDept JSON array contains this information:**

```
{
    "next": {
        "$ref": "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/mfajertest1/department/%7Bid%7D?page=1"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "deptno": 10,
            "dname": "accounting",
            "loc": "madison"
        },
        {
            "deptno": 20,
            "dname": "Finance",
            "loc": "Milwaukee"
        },
        {
            "deptno": 30,
            "dname": "IT",
            "loc": "La Crosse"
        },
        {
            "deptno": 40,
            "dname": "Purchasing",
            "loc": "Green Bay"
        },
        {
            "deptno": 10,
            "dname": "Accounting II",
            "loc": "Madison II"
        },
        {
            "deptno": 50,
            "dname": "Sports",
            "loc": "Waukasha"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would be glad to provide more information regarding this issue if need be.

Comment: Can you show us what `getDept` actually contains? That seems sort of important.

Comment: What does `console.log(getDept.length)` show? Are you sure the JSON is an array, not an object?

Comment: So I've just hit https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/mfajertest1/department/1. The root node is an object, not an array, so you need to query `getDept.items` instead. Thus, I'm downvoting.

Comment: @JamesWright Why not answer with that information, and corrected code, instead?

Comment: @PaulRoub I have added the returned information to the original post.

Comment: @Barmar when i added "console.log(getDept.length)" the log says "undefined." I will look up what that means but can you tell me what that means to you?

Comment: @mfajer Since you have the **Informed** badge, you should know what a downvote is. In case you've forgotten since you joined earlier today, you can [go through the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) again.

Comment: @mjafter a "down vote" means, literally, to cast a negative ("down") vote on your question. Seems like the wrong thing to do on *this* question, which is clear and contains enough information to solve your problem. Don't worry about the votes, check out Josh KG's answer below.

Comment: @JamesWright I can imagine that you find the question unclear, missing  research or not useful. But the fact that you spot the error shouldn't be a reason to vote on the post, IMHO.

Comment: @TylerH thanks. I will check it out again.

Comment: @PaulRoub appreciate your help. Thanks everyone, I got it working. This is my first post on Stack and I will take everyone's advice, regarding posting, going forward. Thanks again.

Comment: @PaulRoub To be fair to the down-voter, he may have done it before the OP edited the question to add the JSON object. At that time, the question was not complete enough to answer, we could only speculate (but notice my earlier comment -- the problem was pretty obvious).

Comment: @Barmar That is precisely the case! Sorry if I came off as a douche PaulRoub and mfajer but without that additional information resulting from your edit, your question was half-baked.

Comment: @rene I made that comment before the OP updated the question with additional information!

Comment: @PaulRoub  I made that comment before the OP updated the question with additional information!

Comment: @JamesWright sure, but I find the comment confusing. It is great if you leave a comment with your down vote because that clarifies the vote. It would be even more helpful if you add what action you expect from the OP. Your comment now reads as a retaliation towards the OP. Not sure if you meant that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON response is actually an object, not an array. The array you're checking for is a property inside that object called `items`. Thus, wherever you are using `getDept`, you should instead be using `getDept.items`:

```
$.getJSON("https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/mfajertest1/department/"+$x('P2_DEPT_NO').value, function(getDept) 
{
    console.log(getDept.items);
    if(getDept.items.length == 0)
        {
                window.alert("No Department with that ID");
        }
    else if(getDept.items.length > 1)
        {   
                apex.navigation.redirect('f?p=71293:11');
        }
    else
        {
    $x('P2_DEPT_NAME').readOnly = false;
    $x('P2_DEPT_NAME').value=getDept.items[0].dname;
    $x('P2_DEPT_NAME').readOnly = true;
    $x('P2_DEPT_LOC').readOnly = false;
    $x('P2_DEPT_LOC').value=getDept.items[0].loc;
    $x('P2_DEPT_LOC').readOnly = true;
    $x('P2_DEPT_NO').readOnly = true;
  }
});
```